# normalized arc length measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

Below is the text of the article *"Frame properties of operator orbits"* by Ole Christensen, DOI: 10.1002/mana.201800344. The actual image is at the bottom.

> In what follows, we write $L^2 := L^2(\mathbb{T})$. By $L^2_+$ we denote the subspace of $L^2$ consisting of all $f \in L^2$ with vanishing negative Fourier coefficients, i.e.,
> $$
> L^2_+ := \left\{ f \in L^2 \left| \int_\mathbb{T} z^nf(z)d|z|=0 \text{ for } n \ge 1\right. \right\},
> $$
> where $d|z|$ indicates integration with respect to the normalized arc length measure.

**My Question:**

I can't understand why the defined set $L^2_+$ is not empty and what is normalized arc length measure $d|z|$ and how to calculate the integral.

---

**The Original Image:**

[image]

Comment: The article can be found [here](https://backend.orbit.dtu.dk/ws/portalfiles/portal/197989433/2018CHP_XI.pdf)

Comment: They are abusing notation a bit. They should really write the integral over the unit circle $S^1$ instead of $\mathbb{T}$. If $\gamma$ parameterizes a piece of $S^1$, then $2\pi \, d|z| = |\gamma'(t)|dt$. E.g., $2 \pi \, d|z| = d\theta$.